# Could not load file or Assembly System.Web.MVC, version=4.0.0.0 , Web publish Activity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

[image]

i am so confused any help will be appreciated, I have VS.Net 2017 and Asp.net MVC 5 , my web publish activity worked until last week ,suddenly i am getting this weird error "Could not load file or Assembly System.Web.MVC, version=4.0.0.0",

Following i did so far,

1.Deleted Bin and Obj folders , rebuild , Run vs.net as admin nothing worked.
2.Tried to install newly installed Nuget packages , nothing worked.
3.Funny thing is i never had Asp.net mvc 4

Please look at my web.config and MVC dll  for more info.

[image]
[image]

Comment: between last working state to now, did you do any updates like upgrading your .net fx version, changing your project fx version?

Comment: No, i haven't made any changes to .Net framework recentely.

Comment: try to clear the GAC cache. i would suggest first check your GAC, gacutil /l System.Net.Http. Then try removing from the cache. then try again, rebuild/update pkg.